# PCB microstrip antenna

Tags: antenna, pcb-antenna, microstrip

I have a query regarding PCB microstrip antennas.
Most of my antennas have been straightforward with the U.fl being placed close to the RF feed point. Maybe a PI filter is added.
But I have seen many PCBs with unique antenna shapes. Point in case, image attached. How are the parameters for these ascertained?

[image]

Comment: Also, in the above image there is no ground pour near the antennas. How come the 3R rule (regarding the spacing of the aground pour from the antenna) does not apply here ?

Answer (score 3):

Designing (PCB) antennas is a science by itself !

The 3R rule you mention probably applies to a certain type/configuration of antennas only. The fact that there are many uniquely shaped antennas tells you that there are many different solutions.

Usually these antennas are designed by a specialist using 3D Elector-Magnetic simulators like [CST](https://www.cst.com/Applications/Category/Antenna+Design+and+Simulation) or [HFSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFSS). This software + some imagination + experience + a little bit of magic can sometimes result in a usable antenna ;-)